# Kendo tooltip empty with LoadContentFrom

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tooltip

When using LoadContentFrom in my Kendo.Tooltip, the tooltip is always empty, all I see is a grey box the size I specified. It does go to the controller to get the data (verified with breakpoint), but after that, nothing.
If I use ContentTemplateId instead, it shows the template, but I really need to get some dynamic data from the server.
What am I missing to fix this?

Thanks

```
<%:Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
    .For("#alertPanel")
    .LoadContentFrom("AlertsDetails", "Home")
    .Width(320).Height(320)
%>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AlertsDetails()
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    //fill list with data ...
    ViewBag.title = "New alerts";
    return PartialView(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: You can't return data the way I was doing. You need to format the data server-side in an HTML string and set the result in the ViewBag.

```
    public ActionResult AlertsDetails()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "<a href='#'>A link</a>";
        return PartialView();
    }
```

and

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<%= ViewBag.Title%>
```

That's it...